# Copy HTML table at once, without looping through cells

Tags: html, vba, excel

I want to **copy the content of a HTML table**. Is it possible to do this **without looping through cells** in the table? (example of what I'm trying to avoid : [Under the comment 'Loop Through Each Table and Download it to Excel in Proper Format](http://officetricks.com/download-html-table-to-excel/).
My table isn't very big, so looping is an option, just wandering if there is a better option.

---

What I have now and suggested method I would prefer:

```
'check all opened windows and find the one with PV output
For Each shlWindow In Shell.Windows
    If TypeName(shlWindow.document) = "HTMLDocument" And shlWindow.LocationName = "PV power estimate information" Then
        Set htmlPopupTables = shlWindow.document.getElementsBytagname("table")
        For Each htmlTabl In htmlPopupTables
            If htmlTabl.classname = "data_table" Then
                ' Question :
                ' htmlTabl.Copy 'or something similar
                ' then paste into my excel sheet
            End If
        Next htmlTabl
    End If
Next
```

I don't have much experience with HTML, so don't hesitate to state even the obvious. :) Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such method like `htmlTable.Copy` but you could use `clipboard` and paste the html content of the table to excel sheet.

*Note: it is necessary to reference internet controls, html object lib. and ms forms. Data will be pasted to active cell on active sheet.*

```
Option Explicit

' Add reference to Microsoft Internet Controls
' Add reference to Microsoft HTML Object Library
' Add reference to Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library

Private Const url As String = "file:///c:/temp/table.html"

Sub test()
    Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim tables As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim table As MSHTML.HTMLTable
    Dim clipboard As MSForms.DataObject

    Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate url

        While .Busy Or .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            DoEvents
        Wend

        Set doc = .document
        Set tables = doc.getElementsByTagName("table")
        Set table = tables(0)
        Set clipboard = New MSForms.DataObject

        clipboard.SetText table.outerHTML
        clipboard.PutInClipboard
        ActiveSheet.Paste

        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

> Demo HTML

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Cell 1</td>
                <td>Cell 2</td>
                <td>Cell 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cell 4</td>
                <td>Cell 5</td>
                <td>Cell 6</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cell 7</td>
                <td>Cell 8</td>
                <td>Cell 9</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

> Result

[image]

Comment: Very interesting! Thank you. I have never worked with these objects. Will give it a try. I have one question regarding the references. If I enable the references ("Internet Controls", etc.) on my computer and give the workbook to user (another computer), will the code work there without the user having to enable them manually?

Comment: Maybe I'll post this as individual question on SO, since it is a bit off topic here.

Comment: @Branislav yes it is interesting, so the Excel does the parsing work for you so you do not have to loop through the rows-cells of the html-table. To the references: the references will work if on the target computer the referenced dll's exist and the user does not have to enable it manually. [Here more info about it](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/missingreferences.aspx).

Comment: @Dee thank you very much for this. I've been searching for hours for a solution like this!

Comment: When you are pasting the table, is there a way to paste it without formatting? I've tried `PasteSpecial` but I still get the formatting.

Comment: @capm Maybe you could use [Range.ClearFormats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.clearformats) method after the _Paste_?

Comment: I went that way but I was hoping for a solution before pasting the values. I did a little research but nothing came up. Thanks anyway.

Comment: `PasteSpecial` is method of `Excel Range` only but here you just paste raw data from clipboard so I think to remove formats after paste is the only solution. You could write your own method to remove formats from the text of the table before paste: `clipboard.SetText RemoveFormating(table.outerHTML)` but is it that important? The formats can easily be removed after paste by Excel itself.