# Getting table data on website via VBA is very slow

Tags: vba

I need to get the table from website via VBA, but the data is very big.
I used array to save every  data, and it cost me over 300 seconds to run it...

**Is there any method to accelerate?**

(I need to key in and click elements to get the table, can I use "msxml2.xmlhttp"?)

(I am not allowed to use SeleniumBasic.)

this is my code:

```
Sub ie_()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    If Weekday(Date) > 1 Then
        w1 = DateAdd("d", -Weekday(Date) + 1, Date)
        w2 = DateAdd("d", -7, w1)
    End If
    date1 = Format(w2, "yyyy-mm-dd")
    date2 = Format(w1, "yyyy-mm-dd")

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate myURL
        
        Set report_btn = .Document.getElementsByClassName("sys-btn")(18)
        report_btn.Click
        Set next_btn = .Document.getElementByid("btnQry")
        next_btn.Click

        'key in element
        .Document.All.txtTxnTime_From.Value = date1
        .Document.All.txtTxnTime_End.Value = date2
        .Document.All.btnQuery.Click

        'search and get the table. Because the data is huge, I used the loop to wait for it....
        Set tbl = .Document.getElementByid("tb_Main")
        Do While tbl Is Nothing
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
            Set tbl = .Document.getElementByid("tb_Main")
        Loop
    End With

    'save the data in table to the array 
    'this step cost almost 300 seconds....
    Set trs = tbl.getElementsByTagName("tr")
    Dim arr() As Variant
    ReDim arr(trs.Length - 1, 25)
    i = 0
    For Each rw In tbl.Rows
        j = 0
        For Each cel In rw.Cells
            arr(i, j) = cel.innertext
            j = j + 1
        Next
        i = i + 1
    Next
    'get the data in array and write to the cell
    For i = 0 To trs.Length - 1
        For j = 0 To 25
            Cells(i + 1, j + 1) = arr(i, j)
        Next
    Next
    'close ie
    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29603458/copy-html-table-at-once-without-looping-through-cells

Comment: Thank you!!! It's very helpful!!
It still runs for long, but make the time 300 sec to 75!
Again, thanks a lot !!